# Java Incompatible conditional operand types int and boolean

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't seem to find a way to fix this error. The error says

> Incompatible conditional operand types int and boolean

```
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
{
        byte byte1 = method229(class32);
        class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1 ? 1 : false);
}
```

If you could tell me how to fix this I'd be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What is `1 : false` supposed to mean? Do you want an `int` or a `boolean`?

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though you want

```
(byte1 == 1 ? true : false)
```

You can't combine different types (`1` and `false`) in the same conditional operator.

In your particular case, it is redundant to use the conditional operator at all, and the following would be sufficient:

```
    class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1);
```

The result of `==` is a boolean and can be assigned to an element of your array (I'm assuming that `aBooleanArray590` is actually an array of booleans and not something else). The parentheses around the `==` expression are optional, but I prefer to use them for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
{
        byte byte1 = method229(class32);
        class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1 ? true : false);
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Ah, the error was a little too obvious. Sorry, my mistake. I've been working 19 hours straight. Guess I need some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use `1` instead of `true`. If that is the case, you can fix it like this.

```
class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1 ? true : false);
```

However, you should be able to skip the `?:` entirely if that is the logic.

```
class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1);
```

On the other hand, if `class32.aBooleanArray590[j]` holds integers, you will need to do this.

```
class32.aBooleanArray590[j] = (byte1 == 1 ? 1 : 0);
```